# Count and identify unique relations in R

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe with 2 columns like this:

```
id1 <- c(123,456,789,122,345,678,901,126,567,890,001,002,130,122)
id2 <- c(121,122,123,456,125,126,127,678,129,130,131,132,890,987)
df <- cbind(id1,id2)
df
  id1 id2
 [1,] 123 121
 [2,] 456 122
 [3,] 789 123
 [4,] 122 456
 [5,] 345 125
 [6,] 678 126
 [7,] 901 127
 [8,] 126 678
 [9,] 567 129
[10,] 890 130
[11,]   1 131
[12,]   2 132
[13,] 130 890
[14,] 122 987
```

Now I can count all the cases where the combination of id1 and id2 equals to combination id2 and id1 and return them, like this:

```
forwards<-paste(V1,V2)
backwards<-paste(V2,V1)

#identifying combinations

intersect(forwards, backwards)
[1] "456 122" "122 456" "678 126" "126 678" "890 130" "130 890"

#count combinations
length(intersect(forwards, backwards))
[1] 6
```

But now, I want a new count for all the cases where id1 is only related with id2 and id2 is only related with id1, for example for df that count will be equal to 4 because:

```
id1==122 is related with id2==456 AND id1==456 is related with id2==122,
but id1 ==122 is too related with id2==987,
```

for this reason the new count should exclude these two cases and count cases like this:

```
  id1 id2
  678 126
  126 678
  890 130
  130 890
  #count should be equals to 4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer to your problem using `data.table`. Perhaps someone could help us find a more straightforward solution.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(id1,id2) # get vectors as a data.table

# create forwards and backwards  columns
  df[ , forwards := paste(id1,id2)]
  df[ , backwards := paste(id2,id1)]

# count number of intersections between forwards and backwards  
  df [ forwards %in% backwards, .(count=.N)]

>    count
> 1:     6
```

Now here is what you're asking, the tricky part.

```
# add new column with number of pairs of id1
  df[ , pairs :=.N, by= id1]

# get all values that have more than one pair
  too_many_pairs <-  as.matrix(df[ pairs >1, .(id1,id2) ])

# solution
  df[  id1 %in% id2 & id2 %in% id1 & !(id1 %in% too_many_pairs) ]

>    id1 id2 
> 1: 678 126 
> 2: 126 678 
> 3: 890 130 
> 4: 130 890
```

Explaining the solution:

The **first part** of the solution `id1 %in% id2 & id2 %in% id1` indicates to keep only those values of id1 that can also be found in id2 and vice-versa

The **second part** of the solution `!(id1 %in% too_many_pairs)` indicates to drop all values of id1 that have more than one pair

Comment: Good answer.  Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Hadleyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# make df a data.frame instead of a matrix
data.frame(df) %>% 
    # add row index
    add_rownames() %>% 
    # melt to long form
    gather(id, val, -rowname) %>% 
    # filter down to values repeated an even number of times
    group_by(val) %>% filter(n() %% 2 == 0) %>% 
    # filter down to rows with two values
    group_by(rowname) %>% filter(n() == 2) %>% 
    # spread back to wide form
    spread(id, val)

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: rowname [4]
# 
#   rowname   id1   id2
#     (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1      10   890   130
# 2      13   130   890
# 3       6   678   126
# 4       8   126   678
```